# how to read log4j config file ffrom tomcat server

Tags: java

I wanted to deploy my application war file without log4j config file inside server but I wanted to read  that log4j file from putting inside server location [means keep in any folder]. so how  will I do

Answer (score 0):

Try to run Tomcat with following VM argument:

```
-Dlog4j.configuration=file:/C:\WORK\devel\workspaces\log4j.properties
```

You can also add debugging mode (to see what paths are in use):

```
-Dlog4j.debug
```

Also try to think about using slf4j with logback. It is faster and you can change configuration parameters without restarting or redeploying application.